# Bootstrap 4 - align to top

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a grid in Bootstrap 4, but i can not quite get it working.

I want to make all the boxes 'float' to the top, but as you can see, the blue box in the codepen sticks below the orange box, but i want it to move up against the red box. I have not yet been able to find out how I can do this, so i was hoping some of you could help me out. :)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="main-content bg-red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="side-one bg-yellow"></div>
      <div class="side-two bg-orange"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-4 col-4">
      <div class="bottom-one bg-blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jeroenknol/pen/yxdajW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already figured it out, i placed the blue block together with the main-content in the col-8 block, and that worked.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="main-content bg-red"></div>
      <div class="offset-6 col-6 bottom-one bg-blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="side-one bg-yellow"></div>
      <div class="side-two bg-orange"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jeroenknol/pen/JaQbWr